# How to move multiple images(retrieved from phpmyadmin) inside a thumbnail using javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I am creating a webpage, which contains images(atleast 3 images in one thumbnail) inside each thumbnails. I am retrieving these images from database. My code is as follows:

```
{foreach $rows as $row}
         <img src="{$row.item_picture}"/> 
    {/foreach}
```

But, I want to store these images in a list so that, i can make the images move continuously inside thumbnail like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C://Users//ts00333776//Desktop//theme.css">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var rice= new Array() // create new array to preload images
            rice[0] = new Image() // create new instance of image object
            rice[0].src = "C://Users//ts00333776//Desktop//images//rice1.jpg" // set image src property to image path, preloading image in the process
            rice[1] = new Image()
            rice[1].src = "C://Users//ts00333776//Desktop//images//rice2.jpg"
            rice[2] = new Image()
            rice[2].src = "C://Users//ts00333776//Desktop//images//rice3.jpg"
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <center>
        <table>
            <tr>
            <td class="first">
                <div class="second">
                    <div class="third">
                        <img src="C://Users//ts00333776//Desktop//images//rice1.jpg" id="slide" height="250px" width="250px"/>
                    </div>
                    <center><h4>some description</h4></center>
                </div>
            </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </center>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        //variable that will increment through the images
        var step=0

        function slideit(){
         //if browser does not support the image object, exit.
         if (!document.images)
          return
         document.getElementById('slide').src = rice[step].src
         if (step<2)
          step++
         else
          step=0
         //call function "slideit()" every 2.5 seconds
         setTimeout("slideit()",2500)
        }

        slideit()

        </script>
    </body>
</html>`
```

But, in the above code, I am retrieving the image from my local, but not from database.
Can anyone help me out to store the images in a list which is retrieved from the phpmyadmin. so that i can move the images inside thumbnail. How can i move the images inside thumbnail which is obtained from database?
Am i going in the right way? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What does this have to do with phpMyAdmin? phpMyAdmin is a tool to manage a database, not a database itself. Perhaps you mean MySQL? What have you tried already? Posting specific error messages or code that isn't working properly can get you more help than asking questions in general terms.

Comment: ya right! I am using MySQL database. I want to retrieve the images stored in database. How can i do this using javascript?

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript cannot connect directly to a MySQL database; you'll need to use a server side scripting language to at least retrieve the results from the database. You can then either use that language to display the results directly in page or pass them to JavaScript (which is more useful if you're doing an autocomplete text field, for instance, but possible less useful if you're just displaying an inline image).

Probably the most commonly used language in this case would be PHP, but you can do this in Python, Perl, Ruby, Java, and more. The biggest deciding factor is probably what your hosting provider makes available for you followed closely by what language you're more familiar with.